# How to reset password with phone number in React Native by using firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, sms

I have already made Firebase login with phone number.(in small React Native App)
Then is it possible to reset password by using phone number?
So I mean, can I receive SMS on my phone to reset password?